# querying elasticsearch on ec2 ubuntu

Tags: amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

I am following this tutorial to learn Elasticsearch, running it on EC2:

http://exploringelasticsearch.com/book/an-overview/up-and-running.html

So I am able to run the server and, using the query tool provided (http://elastichammer.exploringelasticsearch.com/) I can get the status response. However, when I try creating an index with a PUT, I get back the error:

> {   "error": "IndexCreationException[[planet] failed to create index];
>   nested: NoClassDefFoundError[Could not initialize class
>   org.elasticsearch.index.codec.postingsformat.PostingFormats]; ",
>   "status": 500 }

The same thing happens when I use cURL...I can get the sample response with

```
curl -XGET http://ec2-54-218-36-27.us-west-2.compute.amazonawscom:9200/
```

as well as the status with:

```
curl -XGET http://ec2-54-218-36-27.us-west-2.compute.amazonawscom:9200/_status
```

Has anybody experienced this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you deploy a released package or did you build elasticsearch yourself?

Comment: @allstar : Its happening with me now! How did you correct it? My question is posted here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378571/elasticsearch-index-not-opening-due-to-settings

Comment: @javanna : can you please help me out at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378571/elasticsearch-index-not-opening-due-to-settings ?