# Elasticsearch index not opening due to settings

Tags: elasticsearch

While trying some new settings, I did PUT a wrong setting on an index.

The index was closed at that time (as required by ES while PUT-ting in new settings ). 
Now when I try to re-open it, it throws "IndexCreationException" due to those wrong settings.

Even if I try to PUT in a new setting (which I suppose is correct), ES cries about the previous old wrong settings again throwing "IndexCreationException".

So I am unable to remove or update those wrong settings and my index is not opening up now.

My question is, do I have any options other than deleting the whole index and reindexing with corrected settings?

**Update**

[Here is the log](http://hastebin.com/gumujulodi.vhdl) containing the errors.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the exception that you get (paste here the whole stacktrace)?

Comment: @javanna I have updated the question to include the stacktrace. Please check.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this? The logs contain many errors, it would be nice to know what commands you sent, what you got back, and what were the changes applied, step by step.